# Parallel processing for a large raster (split into parts, run a function, and recombine)

Tags: r, spatial, r-raster

The overall goal is to run a correlation analysis on a stacked raster where I use a moving window and correlate the focal pixel stack to the stack of every other pixel in the moving window. The final result is a raster that is the average correlation of that pixel and surrounding pixels. But I am doing this on such a large extent that processing time is massive. I need to separate into sections and run this function on each of the sections and then recombine. Since I am doing a moving window, I also want to overlap the sections be the extent of the moving window, so I do not have an edge effect for large parts of the raster.

I code below for a sample stacked raster and the function for my moving window correlation. I need help on how to separate the raster and then run multiple sections in parallel.

Load packages

```
library(raster)
library(dplyr)
```

First step is make a random 100x100x5 stacked raster. The function I created uses an array, so also changing the raster to an array.

```
# Set the number of rows and columns
num_rows <- 100
num_cols <- 100

# Create an empty raster
empty_raster <- raster(nrows = num_rows, ncols = num_cols)

# Define the number of layers (stack)
num_layers <- 5

# Create a stacked raster with random values for each layer
stacked_raster <- stack(lapply(1:num_layers, function(i) setValues(empty_raster, rpois(ncell(empty_raster), lambda = 10))))

#make data into an array
data <- raster::as.array(stacked_raster)
```

Set some parameters for function

```
y <- dim(data)[3] #number of years of data for correlation



m <- 5 #number of nearest cells you want in each direction 

#create matrix with label for each cell
cell <- matrix(1:10000, 100, 100, byrow=F)

#create distance matrices
lon <- matrix(rep(1:100, 100), nrow=100, ncol=100, byrow = T)
lat <- matrix(rep(1:100, 100), nrow=100, ncol=100, byrow = F)
```

Get ready for the forloop and function creation

```
#get ready for for loop

#create matrix to hold average correlation value for each cell
avg_cor_values <- matrix(NA, 100, 100, byrow=F)

#create function to do the necessary stuff
corr_function <- function(i){
  focal <- which(cell==i, arr.ind=T)
  
  #get min and max lat and lon for desired grid
  min_lon <- focal[1] - m
  #set min lon to 1 if calculation is negative
  if(min_lon < 1){
    min_lon <- 1
  }
  
  max_lon <- focal[1] + m
  #set max lon to nrow(lon) if calculation is more than nrow(lon)
  if(max_lon > nrow(lon)){
    max_lon <- nrow(lon)
  }
  
  min_lat <- focal[2] - m
  #set min lat to 1 if calculation is negative
  if(min_lat < 1){
    min_lat <- 1
  }
  
  max_lat <- focal[2] + m
  #set max lat to ncol(lat) if calculation is more than ncol(lat)
  if(max_lat > ncol(lat)){
    max_lat <- ncol(lat)
  }
  
  #create dataframe with position of each cell that needs correlation calculation
  focal_grid <- expand.grid(lon=min_lon:max_lon, lat=min_lat:max_lat)
  
  #determine which row in focal_grid matches the focal cell location
  drop_row1 <- which(focal_grid[1:nrow(focal_grid),1]==focal[1], arr.ind=T)  
  drop_row2 <- which(focal_grid[1:nrow(focal_grid),2]==focal[2], arr.ind=T)
  #remove the focal cell from the grid
  focal_grid <- focal_grid[-drop_row1[which(drop_row1 %in% drop_row2)],]
  
  #calculate correlation between focal cell and all cells within focal grid
  cor_results <- NA
  for(n in 1:nrow(focal_grid)){
    cor_results[n] <- cor(data[focal[1], focal[2], 1:y], data[focal_grid[n,1], focal_grid[n,2], 1:y], use = "pairwise.complete.obs") 
  }
  
  avg_cor_values[focal[1], focal[2]] <- mean(cor_results, na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

Run the function on the raster

```
corr_function_vec <- Vectorize(corr_function)

#run code for all cells in grid
Sys.time()
product <- corr_function_vec(1:max(cell))
Sys.time()

corr_product <- matrix(product, 100, 100, byrow=F)
corr_raster <- raster(corr_product)
plot(corr_raster)
```

Comment: I do not understand your description of what you want to do, but perhaps you can use `terra::focalReg` or `terra::focalPairs`

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I should be more clear. I do not need to run analysis between rasters in the stack. Each pixel is a time series. So I am running a function that correlates the time series of the focal pixel to all other pixels in a moving window. I do have code to do this (although if there is a better way, I would be open to suggestions). My main goal is to find a way to make this run faster. In my head, I could split the raster into overlapping tiles, run my function on each of these tiles in parallel and then recombine them. But I really do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on a unix-alike (Linux or macOS), the following can use your function and speed up over your available cores. I time both the serial and parallel versions below. Running on an M3 mac with 12 cores (6 performance + 6 efficiency cores) produces about 7x speedup.

```
#run serial code for all cells in grid
system.time({
  product <- corr_function_vec(1:max(cell))
})

#run parallel code for all cells in grid
system.time({
  cores <- parallel::detectCores()
  product2 <- parallel::mclapply(1:max(cell), corr_function, mc.cores = cores)
  product2 <- do.call(c, product2)
})
all.equal(product, product2)
```

The output from the above is:

```
> #run serial code for all cells in grid
> system.time({
+   product <- corr_function_vec(1:max(cell))
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
 18.178   0.072  18.261 

> #run parallel code for all cells in grid
> system.time({
+   cores = parallel::detectCores()
+   product2 <- parallel::mclapply(1:max(cell), corr_fu .... [TRUNCATED] 
   user  system elapsed 
 25.638   0.996   2.612 

> all.equal(product, product2)
[1] TRUE
```

The `Vectorize` function already uses `mapply` under the covers, so this just replaces it with `mclapply` from the **parallel** package. You can skip the `mc.cores` argument in most cases as I only supply the default for clarity.

If you want to be portable to Windows, the **future** package together with **furrr** would work too, but on Windows you would be duplicating the `cell` array in each parallel instance (because there the Unix `fork` that is under `mclapply` is not available for shared-memory parallel computing).

There are more options and more speedup if you have a cluster and want to split the `cell` array across the nodes, but here it gets more complicated because of the needed overlaps or combining partial results. Of course, clusters are collections of Linux boxes so `fork` is available and you can have just one full copy of `cell` per node. The complication would be combining partial results across the nodes, which is easily done with the package **pbdMPI** simplified MPI.